# Programatically render a node in a specific language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I want to render a node display programmatically for sending it to a search engine. It works ok but is ignoring the language and renders the field labels in the source language (which is English).

I use the following code for creating the teaser markup.

```
 $render_array_teaser = $view_builder->view($entity, 'compact_teaser', 'de');
 $rendered_teaser = $renderer->renderPlain($render_array_teaser);
```

The result gives me a teaser that includes a field named "field_sku" that has the label "SKU number". If I output the teaser in the browser the label gets correctly translated to German = "Artikelnummer" if the current language is "German".

If I render the teaser with the above code the label stays English even if I set the langcode parameter to 'de'.

How to get the teaser with German lables?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The field labels are used from the config translation system. You also need to set the config override language. See [`user_mail()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_mail/8.2.x) in core.

```
  // Temporarily alter the language manager.
  $language_manager = \Drupal::languageManager();
  $langcode = $message['langcode'];
  $variables = array('user' => $params['account']);

  $language = \Drupal::languageManager()->getLanguage($params['account']->getPreferredLangcode());
  $original_language = $language_manager->getConfigOverrideLanguage();
  $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($language);
  $mail_config = \Drupal::config('user.mail');

  // Restore the language manager.
  $language_manager->setConfigOverrideLanguage($original_language);
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I added the link to the documentation page, and the relevant code. I hope I got the relevant one.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this do not works anymore - see https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3061599 :-(

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/138956)