# get field list translation

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a list field on Profile entity for civilities.
I want to get the value of this field in a specific value whatever is the current one.
Since the Profile isn't translatable I can't get a way to achieve that.
Any help is welcome

Comment: Can you give an example how it should look in different languages?

Comment: I added a field civility on a commerce_order type.
The field is a translated select list :
001|M.|Mr.
002|Mme|Mrs

commerce_order itself isn't translatable, I can't get a way to get the civility string value in a specific lang

Comment: The translated select list is the same as the field label or help text of the translated field settings. It is displayed in the detected interface text language.

Comment: This work fine, but how can I programmaticaly specify the language ?

Comment: You need to override the config language, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202483/programatically-render-a-node-in-a-specific-language

Comment: I don't see any difference