# Programmatically render a view as HTML

Tags: views, 8

I am using a custom function. In a button click i want to display view page. Here i want to render my view programatically in html format. How can i do that?

This is my jquery code:

```
$('.view-all-content').click(function () {

  $.post("/callajax", {
    'action': 'get_data_from_view',

  }, function (data) {

    console.log(data)

    // if (data == "gg") {
    //    console.log("suc")
    // }

    $(".view-all-content-result").html(data);

  });

});
```

In my function.php

```
function get_data_from_view() {

  $view = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render(views_embed_view('article_list', 'page_5'));

  // Other code ...

  echo $view;
}
```

Comment: explain a little more on what you are trying to acheive. If you are trying to render a view programatically then see : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205722/how-do-i-programmatically-render-a-view-with-contextual-filters

Comment: `function.php`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I programmatically render a view with contextual filters?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205722/how-do-i-programmatically-render-a-view-with-contextual-filters)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
\Drupal::service('renderer')->render(views_embed_view('VIEWSID', 'DISPLAYID'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I am using a function.php file in my theme root folder.When i have tried with this code showing errror "this function () doesn't exist in your file functions.php".I have added use Drupal\views\Views; namespace.Is it correct?

Comment: I just tested this code myself and don't need a namespace for it.  The falling `this` is probably something else in your code ... please post your code at least the relevant part.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have copied the code to .module file.It is working now.Thanks.

Comment: Hello,how to pass language code to \Drupal::service('renderer')->render(views_embed_view('article_list', 'page_5',));.I have tried with \Drupal::service('renderer')->render(views_embed_view('article_list', 'page_5',$languageCode));.But not working.My issue is when click on a button,iam getting view result in english.But in arabic page the same english result is showing.

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/202483/programatically-render-a-node-in-a-specific-language

Answer (score 2):

You try install module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak)
render block view twig

```
{{ drupal_view('who_s_new', 'block_1') }}
```

render block set arguments

```
{{ drupal_view('products_by_category', 'block_1', tid) }}
```

You can see it https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/twig-tweak/twig-tweak-and-views